# ClickOnce Deployment - FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, caching, visual-studio-2013, clickonce, publish

I'm having a problem using ClickOnce,
It is an online Clickonce.
My project is C# project built in Visual Studio 2013.

The application works on 99% of the machines , but there are few computers which it doesnt deploy containing the error:

> Following errors were detected during this operation.   * [16/08/2015
>   14:19:05] System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>         - The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
>         - Source: mscorlib
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateActContext(CreateActContextParameters&
>   Params)           at
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateActContext(IDefinitionAppId
>   AppId)            at
>   System.ActivationContext.CreateFromName(ApplicationIdentity
>   applicationIdentity)          at
>   System.ActivationContext.CreatePartialActivationContext(ApplicationIdentity
>   identity)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId
>   appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter,
>   Boolean useActivationParameter)           at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>   state)

The error occur in the end of the installion, but I suppose it doesnt really install (there are some files in the appdata folder, but when I click the ClickOnce installer again, it reinstall it from 0)

I've done some research, and I got to the registry key :

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\OnlineAppQuotaUsageEstimate

Which is the cache location for online Clickonce applications.

- On the computers which works, after the installer the value change to 837207846
- On the computers which the ClickOnce doesnt work, it changes to 0.

any suggestions how to fix that problem?